# Bash - Sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N - timed-out

Tags: bash

I'm trying to calculate the sum of all the multiples of `3` or `5` below `N` in bash but my attempts fail at the speed benchmark.

The input format is described as follow:

> The first line is `T`, which denotes the number of test cases, followed by `T` lines, each containing a value of `N`.
>
> Sample input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 10
> 100
> ```
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> 23
> 2318
> ```

Here are my attemps:

- With `bc`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

readarray input

printf 'n=%d-1; x=n/3; y=n/5; z=n/15; (1+x)*x/2*3 + (1+y)*y/2*5 - (1+z)*z/2*15\n' "${input[@]:1}" |
bc
```

- With pure `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read t
while (( t-- ))
do
    read n
    echo "$(( --n, x=n/3, y=n/5, z=n/15, (1+x)*x/2*3 + (1+y)*y/2*5 - (1+z)*z/2*15 ))"
done
```

<sup>**remark:** I'm using `t` because the input doesn't end with a newline...</sup>

Both solutions are evaluated as "too slow", but I really don't know what could be further improved. Do you have an idea?

Comment: This might be useful: [A126592 - Sum of numbers less than or equal to n which are multiples of 3 or 5](https://oeis.org/A126592) at [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/).

Comment: @pjh Thank you; the formula seems to be the same as the one in the question. I'm thinking of accepting @oguzismail answer because it shows an optimized version of it. Sadly, `awk` doesn't have enough integer precision so I can't use it directly; the best I could do was to pre-process the input with `awk` and pipe it to `bc`; yet, that's also considered "too slow". I'm about to conclude that it's impossible to satisfy the constraints with bash + standard tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  split("0 0 3 3 8 14 14 14 23 33 33 45 45 45", sums)
  split("0 0 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 6", ns)
}
NR > 1 {
  print fizzbuzz_sum($0 - 1)
}
function fizzbuzz_sum(x, q, r) {
  q = int(x / 15)
  r = x % 15
  return q*60 + q*(q-1)/2*105 + sums[r] + (x-r)*ns[r]
}
```

It's pretty fast on my old laptop that has an AMD A9-9410 processor

```
$ printf '%s\n' 2 10 100 | awk -f fbsum.awk
23
2318
$
$ time seq 0 1000000 | awk -f fbsum.awk >/dev/null

real    0m1.532s
user    0m1.542s
sys     0m0.010s
$
```

And with `bc`, in case you need it to be capable of handling big numbers too:

```
{
  cat <<EOF
s[1] = 0; s[2] = 0; s[3] = 3; s[4] = 3; s[5] = 8
s[6] = 14; s[7] = 14; s[8] = 14; s[9] = 23; s[10] = 33
s[11] = 33; s[12] = 45; s[13] = 45; s[14] = 45

n[1] = 0; n[2] = 0; n[3] = 1; n[4] = 1; n[5] = 2
n[6] = 3; n[7] = 3; n[8] = 3; n[9] = 4; n[10] = 5
n[11] = 5; n[12] = 6; n[13] = 6; n[14] = 6

define f(x) {
  auto q, r
  q = x / 15
  r = x % 15
  return q*60 + q*(q-1)/2*105 + s[r] + (x-r)*n[r]
}

EOF
  awk 'NR > 1 { printf "f(%s - 1)\n", $0 }'
} | bc
```

It's much slower though.

```
$ printf '%s\n' 2 10 100 | sh ./fbsum.sh
23
2318
$ 
$ time seq 0 1000000 | sh ./fbsum.sh >/dev/null

real    0m4.980s
user    0m5.224s
sys     0m0.358s
$
```

Comment: Thanks you @oguzismail. With `awk` I get a "_Wrong Answer_". It seems that the calculations need GNU's `--bignum` option, which apprently isn't available on the VM: `awk: unrecognized option: bignum` `BusyBox v1.30.1 (2019-06-12 17:51:55 UTC) multi-call binary.`

Comment: @Fravadona bc it is then. See my edit

Comment: That's right, it is much slower and doesn't pass the constraints... but I concluded that their requirements are impossible to satisfy with bash and standard tools.

Comment: With the bash solution, and `1000000 seq 1 1000000`, you could go to bed and get up the next morning and it would still be churning away on a single core pegged at 100%...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, your expectations for a pure Bash solution are a bit pessimistic.  I've posted Bash code that can process one million inputs in 40 seconds.  That's poor compared to `awk` or other alternatives, but it's not unspeakably awful.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from the basics and try to optimize it as much as possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read N
sum=0
for ((i=1;i<N;++i)); do
  if ((i%3 == 0 )) || (( i%5 == 0 )); then
      (( sum += i ))
  fi
done
echo $sum
```

In the above, we run the loop *N* times, perform minimally *N* comparisons and maximally *2N* sums (i and sum). We could speed this up by doing multiple loops with steps of 3 and 5, however, we have to take care of double counting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read N
sum=0
for ((i=N-N%3;i>=3;i-=3)); do (( sum+=i )); done
for ((i=N-N%5;i>=5;i-=5)); do (( i%3 == 0 )) && continue; ((sum+=i)); done
echo $sum
```

We have now maximally *2N/3 + 2N/5 = 16N/15* sums and *N/5* comparisons. This is already much faster. We could still optimise it by adding an extra loop with a step of 3*5 to subtract the double counting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read N
sum=0
for ((i=N-N%3 ; i>=3 ; i-=3 )); do ((sum+=i)); done
for ((i=N-N%5 ; i>=5 ; i-=5 )); do ((sum+=i)); done
for ((i=N-N%15; i>=15; i-=15)); do ((sum-=i)); done
echo $sum
```

This brings us to maximally *2(N/3 + N/5 + N/15) = 17N/15* additions and zero comparisons. This is optimal, however, we still have a call to an arithmetic expression per cycle. This we could absorb into the for-loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read N
sum=0
for ((i=N-N%3 ; i>=3 ; sum+=i, i-=3 )); do :; done
for ((i=N-N%5 ; i>=5 ; sum+=i, i-=5 )); do :; done
for ((i=N-N%15; i>=15; sum-=i, i-=15)); do :; done
echo $sum
```

Finally, the easiest would be to use the formula of the [Arithmetic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) removing all loops. Having in mind that bash uses integer arithmetic (i.e `m = p*(m/p) + m%p`), one can write

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read N
(( sum = ( (3 + N-N%3) * (N/3) + (5 + N-N%5) * (N/5) - (15 + N-N%15) * (N/15) ) / 2 ))
echo $sum
```

The latter is the fastest possible way (with the exception of numbers below 15) as it does not call any external binary such as `bc` or `awk` and performs the task without any loops.

Comment: You miss `N--`:  *below N*!!: `echo $(( N--,  ( (3 + N-N%3) * (N/3) + (5 + N-N%5) * (N/5) - (15 + N-N%15) * (N/15) ) / 2 ))`

Comment: Added `((...))` in line `for ((i=N-N%5;i>=5;i-=5)); do (( i%3 == 0 )) && continue; ((sum+=i));`

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

s35() {
    m=$(($1-1)); echo $(seq -s+ 3 3 $m) $(seq -s+ 5 5 $m) 0 | bc   
}

read t
while read n
do
    s35 $n
done
```

or

```
s35() {
    m=$(($1-1)); 
    { sort -nu <(seq 3 3 $m) <(seq 5 5 $m) | tr '\n' +; echo 0; } | bc   
}
```

to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code processes input from `echo 1000000; seq 1000000` (one million inputs) in 40 seconds on an unexotic Linux VM:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

a=( -15  1 -13 -27 -11 -25 -9  7 -7 -21 -5 11 -3 13 -1 )
b=(   0 -8  -2  18  22  40 42 28 28  42 40 22 18 -2 -8 )

read -r t
while (( t-- )); do
    read -r n
    echo "$(( m=n%15, ((7*n+a[m])*n+b[m])/30 ))"
done
```

The code depends on the fact that the sum for each value `n` can be calculated with a quadratic function of the form `(7*n**2+A*n+B)/30`.  The values of `A` and `B` depend on the value of `n` modulo 15. The arrays `a` and `b` in the code contain the values of `A` and `B` for each possible modulus value (`{0..14}`).  (To avoid doing the algebra I wrote a little Bash program to generate the `a` and `b` arrays.)

The code can easily be translated to other programming languages, and would run much faster in many of them.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure bash approach,

```
#!/bin/bash

DBG=1

echo -e "This will generate the series sum for multiples of each of 3 and 5 ..."
echo -e "\nEnter the number of summation sets to be generated => \c"
read sets

for (( k=1 ; k<=${sets} ; k++))
do
    echo -e "\n============================================================"
    echo -e "Enter the maximum value of a multiple => \c"
    read max
    echo ""

    for multiplier in 3 5
    do
        sum=0
        iter=$((max/${multiplier}))
        for (( i=1 ; i<=${iter} ; i++ ))
        do
            next=$((${i}*${multiplier}))
            sum=$((sum+=${next}))
            test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\t ${next}   ${sum}"
        done
        echo -e "TOTAL:  ${sum}  for ${iter} multiples of ${multiplier} <= ${max}\n"
    done
done
```

**The session log when DBG=1:**

```
This will generate the series sum for multiples of each of 3 and 5 ...

Enter the number of summation sets to be generated => 2

============================================================
Enter the maximum value of a multiple => 15

     3   3
     6   9
     9   18
     12   30
     15   45
TOTAL:  45  for 5 multiples of 3 <= 15

     5   5
     10   15
     15   30
TOTAL:  30  for 3 multiples of 5 <= 15


============================================================
Enter the maximum value of a multiple => 12

     3   3
     6   9
     9   18
     12   30
TOTAL:  30  for 4 multiples of 3 <= 12

     5   5
     10   15
TOTAL:  15  for 2 multiples of 5 <= 12
```

Answer (score 1):

While `awk` will always be faster than shell, with bash you can use `((m % 3 == 0)) || ((m % 5 == 0))` to identify the multiples of `3` and `5` less than `n`. You will have to see if it passes the time constraints, but it should be relatively quick,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -i t n sum        ## handle t, n and sum as integer values

read t || exit 1          ## read t or handle error

while ((t--)); do         ## loop t times
  sum=0                   ## initialize sum zero
  read n || exit 1        ## read n or handle error
  ## loop from 3 to < n
  for ((m = 3; m < n; m++)); do
    ## m is multiple of 3 or multiple of 5
    ((m % 3 == 0)) || ((m % 5 == 0)) && {
      sum=$((sum + m))    ## add m to sum
    }
  done
  echo $sum               ## output sum
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the script in `mod35sum.sh` and your data in `dat/mod35sum.txt` you would have:

```
$ bash sum35mod.sh < dat/sum35mod.txt
23
2318
```